# Cannot delete file due to empty entity reference

Tags: 8, files

I have been asked to delete a file that has incorrect legal information on it from a website so it has to go. My users could not do it.

The site is running drupal 8.9.13 and I have installed the module [file_delete](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_delete)

When I try to delete the file I get the following error message:

```
The file ND Pamphlet re Employee Assistance Program .pdf cannot be deleted because it is in use by the following modules: file.
Click here to see its usages.
```

There is one reference to a node that does not use this file. Though it may have once been linked to on that node.

I tried deleting the node itself - as it was relatively small and I thought it could be recreated. The error however remains. When I now look at the usage information for the file I see the following:

[image]

Caches have been cleared and cron run several times. How do I remove this file and this non-existent reference?

Additionally, why does this happen and how can it be avoided in the future?

Comment: Hi, tanbog! Any updates regarding this? Looks like I have the same issue and any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: I had the same issue and found that https://www.drupal.org/project/file_delete_ui was able to let my admin users delete files without checking file usage. Admins must be careful though...